# what does it mean for a string to begin another string? c++

Tags: c++, string

I'm attempting to complete an o'reilly textbook on my own and the questions are beginning to become very difficult to me. I read every page up to the programming problems so I should understand. But could someone explain what this question means? "write a function begins(string1, string2) that returns true if string1 begins string2. write a program to test the function"

Lets start with what I do know, I know how to create a function and call it in main. What I dont know is what it means for a string to begin another string and how I would even go about it. An explanation would be nice. If you provide any code to for an example, please don't answer the entire function or program. I'm really trying to learn, and would like to complete the program on my own. Thanks.

---

Thanks for the help guys, but now, I'm running into an issue when trying to run my program. I type "hel" for string1 and "hello" for string2. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string string1;
std::string string2;
bool begins(std::string string1, std::string string2);


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter two strings: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, string1);
    std::getline(std::cin, string2);

    begins(string1, string2);
    std::cout << string1 << "begins" << string2;


    return 0;
```

}

```
bool begins(std::string string1, std::string string2)
{
    if (begins(string1, string2) == true)
        return true;

    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I think he's missing a word. "... returns true if string1 begins WITH string2"

Comment: It *sounds* like the function wants you to see if string1 "begins with" string2.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: strstr() is a C function to start, but this could be done with little effort directly once you get used to the language a bit more.

Comment: @BagelzoneHa'bonè maybe the textbook is missing a word. But how I phrased it is exactly how its phrased in the book.

Comment: Now you need to implement `begins` without calling `begins`. Take a look at my answer for a short description of the algorithm (I deliberately did not write any code to avoid "spoilers").

Comment: @dasblinkenlight spoilers are welcome now, now that I have majority of the program complete and understand what it going on, getting it to work properly if my first priority. Once I can get the basic program to run, then I will attempt to take the corner cases into effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String begins another string is another way of saying that a string is a prefix of another string. Here is an example: `hell` is a prefix of `hello`.

The check algorithm is relatively straightforward: start comparing strings character by character, until either (1) the candidate prefix string ends, or (2) you find a difference. If prefix ends before you find a difference, return `true`; otherwise, return `false`:

```
bool begins(std::string string1, std::string string2)
{
    if (string1.size() > string2.size) return false;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != string1.size() ; i++) {
        if (string1[i] != string2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;   
}
```

Testing this function should check the two "mainstream" cases (i.e. when `string1` is a prefix of `string2`, and when `string1` is not a prefix of `string2`) and several "corner cases":

- **The first string is empty** - return `true`, because an empty string is a prefix of any string.
- **The second string is empty** - return `true` when the first string is also empty, or `false` otherwise.
- **The first string is longer than the second string** - return `false` even if you see a full match between the shorter second string and the longer "prefix".

Comment: Thanks man, so what the implementation does is go through each character and if each character in string 1 isn't in string 2, it returns a false value?

Comment: @MauriceAbney Yes, if any character is different, then `string1` is not a prefix of `string2`. If the loop finishes without returning, then the `string1` has finished without finding a difference, so we can return `true`.

Comment: I believe I might have run into a problem. Although my code now runs, it takes any string and says it begins any string. ie "the begins cow" which I know is false. Is there something wrong with my main function or the implementation of begins? could you try running it to see if you run into the same problem?

Comment: @MauriceAbney Your `main` function ignores the return value of `begins(a,b)`. You need an `if` statement around the `cout << ...` line, and optionally an `else` to print a "does not begin ..." message.

Answer (score 2):

String `"Hell"` begins string `"Hello World"`.

Hence, this code-snippet should print out the `"This is correct"` message in both statements.

```
if (begins("Hell", "Hello World") == true) {
    cout << "This is correct" << endl;
}

if (begins("globe", "Hello World") == false) {
    cout << "This is also correct" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation man. I would have never figured thats what it meant. But now, I have a problem somewhere in my code and it's not running properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess this means that the start of string2 == string1. For example, if `string1` is "foo" and `string2` is "foobar".

Answer (score 1):

In C++ a string is just an array of characters.

```
| H | E | L | L | O |  | W | O | R | L | D | \0 |
```

Above is a string that represents `"Hello World"`.

The function in question would do something like this

```
bool begins(std::string A, std::string B)
{
  return A.substr(0, B.length()) == B;
}
```

This would check if string `B` matches a substring of `A` starting from position `0`.

```
begins("Hello World", "Hello") -> True
begins("Hello World", "Goodbye World") -> False
```